# Tikz: How do I store coordinates of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to get 2 X values of a node (west and east), save them as variables and then do some calculations with them. Here is some pseudo code that obviously doesn't work:

```
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    

\path let
    \p{W}=(node1.west),
    \p{E}=(node1.east)
in
    \def\nWest{\x{W}} % Here, I get an error everytime I try to any commands
    \def\nEast{\x{E}}
;
\def\nWidth {} % Also, is it possible to do calculations right here in the definition?
\FPeval\num{clip((nEast-nWest)/3)} % This may be more complex in the final code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=3cm](node1) {};
\path
  let
  \p1=(node1.west),
  \p2=(node1.east),
  \n1={abs(\x2-\x1)/3} in node[
    draw,red,
    minimum width=\n1,] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `\def` (or `\xdef`) etc here, use `\pgfextra` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=3cm](node1) {};
\path
  let
  \p1=(node1.west),
  \p2=(node1.east),
  \n1={abs(\x2-\x1)/3} in
  \pgfextra{
    \newlength{\mylen}
    \setlength{\mylen}{\n1}
    }
    node[
    draw,red,
    minimum width=\mylen,] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, but now I have a new problem. Is there any way to do something like this (Imagine I have a \newcommand somewhere in there): \foreach \int in {0,1,...,#3-1} {} % Subtracting 1 from the argument #3

Comment: @Areuz I am not in a position to imagine (tired). Only if you give enough details and some code please. Which quantity is #3 actually?

Comment: Posting it there in the comments would be ugly, here you go: http://pastebin.com/uxDAc1NM

Comment: Sorry about the {nPorts} missed it while cleaning up a other part of the code.

Comment: @Areuz This new question has nothing to do with the original one, so I'd think the best thing to do is to opena new question.